# Updating several model instances at the same time, The Rails Way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `settings` table with two fields, `key` and `value`. Now, while creating an administration section for it I want to be able to edit all settings at once.

Is there a "Rails (3) way" to do this that will save me some time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord has an `update_all` method for updating all the records with the specified string of column and value pairs that match the usual conditions etc. that `find` supports. The method issues a single SQL UPDATE statement behind the scenes.

For example:

```
Setting.update_all("key = 'foo', value = 'bar'")
```

—equates to:

```
UPDATE settings SET key='foo', value='bar';
```

- [`update_all` API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001787)

If you want to perform a mass update of multiple settings with different key/value values then there are a couple of Railscasts that cover how to do this:

- [Episode #165: Edit Multiple](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple)
- [Episode #198: Edit Multiple Individually](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually)

Comment: Is there something like `form_for(@all_settings)` that can be used together with update_all?